# Why am i getting this token error even though I have set it up correctly?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot using dicord.js. And I have this following code in index.js.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { BOT_TOKEN, APP_ID, GUILD_ID } = process.env;
    const client = new Client({ intents: [], rest: { version: '10' } });

client.rest.setToken(BOT_TOKEN);


async function main() {
  try {
    client.slashCommands = new Collection();
    await registerCommands(client, '../commands');
    console.log(client.slashCommands);
    const slashCommandsJson = client.slashCommands.map((cmd) =>
      cmd.getSlashCommandJSON()
    );
    console.log(slashCommandsJson);
    await client.rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(APP_ID, GUILD_ID), {
      body: slashCommandsJson,
    });
    const registeredSlashCommands = await client.rest.get(
      Routes.applicationGuildCommands(APP_ID, GUILD_ID)
    );
    console.log(registeredSlashCommands);
    await client.login(BOT_TOKEN);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

main();`
```

I have set up the token code in .env file and yet i am still getting this error which I am not quite sure about

```
Error: Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present
at _RequestManager.resolveRequest (C:\Users\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\RequestManager.cjs:142:15)
at _RequestManager.queueRequest (C:\Users\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\RequestManager.cjs:115:46)
at REST.raw (C:\Users\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:56:32)
at REST.request (C:\Users\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:33)
at REST.put (C:\Users\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:46:17)
at main (C:\Users\src\index.js:31:23)
```

Comment: i have done the both @Caladan

Comment: does it work when putting the token in instead of using the env file?

Answer (score 0):

I Actually Dont Know About ENV. So I Recommend Making A Config File Or Apply Token Directly :)